# Disabling Local JMX Connections on JVM

Tags: java, memory, heap-memory, dump, jconsole

We are writing a java program which keeps a password in memory. Unfortunately, the user can easily use jconsole or jmap to create a heap dump file and open it to find the password. I think jconsole connects jvm using local sockets. I wanna know, is there any way to disable jmx even for local users? Is there any way to totally disable heap dumps? As the user have access to the memory segment, this is possible to access the password anyway. However, I wanna disable standards ways of doing that to make the action as expensive as possible.

Answer (score 6):

Finally, I found a solution for disabling jconsole connections. It also prevents jmap to create a dump file. I found the solution [here](http://forums-beta.sun.com/thread.jspa?messageID=10042966). I also quote the answer here:

> You can prevent tools such as
>   jconsole and others from connecting by
>   running with the
>   -XX:+DisableAttachMechanism option. Note that this option is not
>   documented/supported but should do
>   what you want. That said, even with
>   this there is nothing to stop you
>   connect gdb or other debugging/proc
>   based programs

However, that is obvious the memory segment could be accessed locally. But, does anyone knows a tool to make standard memory dumps with direct access to the memory?

Comment: Not necessarily a standard memory dump format, but you can use for example the HxD hex editor (http://mh-nexus.de/en/hxd/) to access the memory of any local process (given enough privileges).

Comment: -XX:+DisableAttachMechanism does not seem to be disabling the JMX. I was still able to connect using jvisualvm. Did it worked for you? @mohsen

Answer (score 3):

Setting the max connection count to zero shuts down JMX

```
-Dsun.rmi.transport.tcp.maxConnectionThreads=0
```

If you still need stats, simple read the corresponding hsperfdata_* file

Edit:
I published my [hsperf munin plugin](https://github.com/bebbodl/hsperf) on github.