# Tomcat Keep Listening to tcp 1099 port

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat8, rmi, jmx

I have application deployed on tomcat 8.5.63 version and Java 1.8 version. Whenever I am deploying the application tomcat is opening up tcp port 1099 for JMX rmi by default. And to which I am able to connect without any authentication from remote client using jvisualvm tool. I don't want that port to get opened up by default. I have tried changing the various jvm arguments based on other solution in SO but no luck.
Given below are the recent configuration which I have tried.

```
CATALINA_OPTS="-Xms512m -Xmx1024m -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=16105 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=true -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.login.config=Tomcat -Djava.security.auth.login.config=$CATALINA_HOME/login.config -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.access.file=$CATALINA_BASE/conf/jmxremote.access -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=16106
```

I have specifically mentioned the **-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=16106** to be used for JMX rmi but not able to understand why it still listening to port 1099. Please advise.

Note: I did saw some answers mentioning to pass **XX:+DisableAttachMechanism** as jvm argument to block jxm. But what if we want to have have jxm also enabled and default port(1099) should not be used.

Comment: How do you start Tomcat? Through the `catalina.sh/startup.sh` scripts or in a different  way?

Comment: Using start Script only.

Comment: Then check if any of the scripts contains other `com.sun.management` properties (except those you gave in your question) and whether the default `management.properties` file (in the JRE installation folder) does not provide the port 1099. There is no default port for JMX.

Comment: I checked there are no other properties other than mentioned in question. Also I verified management.properties file as well, it does not provide 1099. And yes JMX does not have default port but for RMI 1099 port is default If I am not wrong.

Comment: By default the RMI port is `0`, i.e. random. You can add `logProps="true"` to the `<VersionLoggerListener>` in your `server.xml` to check what are the actual system properties values when Tomcat starts.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65323367/why-tomcat-server-is-accessible-thru-jmxrmi-port-1099

Comment: @ChristopherSchultz: I did check your answer there but even when I am passing -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=16106 the port 1099 is still open. Also I tried to pass XX:+DisableAttachMechanism as well but still the same issue. Please advise.

Comment: Did you try directing Tomcat to set the port for you?

Comment: So is this question answered yet?  I have same issue. Port 1099 is unauthenticated. It is clearly security vulnerability.  Whats the point of defining "-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port" and enabling authentication on it, when you can simply connect on port 1099.   1099 is wide open, which shouldnt be.

Comment: Correct even I am still facing the same issue. There is no answer yet for this.

Comment: @GauravParek Did you find any solution for this ? I am facing same issue ?

Comment: @Yogi_NE Did you find any solution for this ? I am facing same issue ?

Comment: No, this question is still open.